# Why can't I move my generic constructor into a .cpp file?

Tags: .net, generics, c++-cli

If I do this in a header file alone, it works fine:

```
generic<typename T>
ref class MyGenericClass
{
protected:
    T m_someInternalInformation;

public:
    MyGenericClass(void)
    {

    }
};
```

...but if I alter the .h file to look like this:

```
generic<typename T>
ref class MyGenericClass
{
protected:
    T m_someInternalInformation;

public:
    MyGenericClass();
};
```

...and a .cpp file like this:

```
#include "MyGenericClass.h"

MyGenericClass::MyGenericClass(void)
{

}
```

I get a compiler error:

```
1>MyGenericClass.cpp(4): error C2955: 'MyGenericClass' : use of class generic requires generic argument list
```

I've tried adding the generic definition about the constructor definition:

```
#include "MyGenericClass.h"

generic<typename T>
MyGenericClass::MyGenericClass(void)
{

}
```

...but I get the same error. What am I missing here?

Comment: Well spotted. Too much back-and-forth when I was cobbling together my example. I've corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
generic<typename T>
MyGenericClass<T>::MyGenericClass(void)
{

}
```

Note the `<T>` before the `::`.